# Why should we not hang the photos of the living people on the south side wall?

Tags: scripture, belief

MY Parents refuse to allow photos hangings on the south direction of the room. Why is it so?

does hindu scriptures forbids it?

Thanks.

Comment: South is the direction of Yama (dikpal of the south). After death people are supposed to go to the southern direction. As per Vastu too they say the photos of departed ancestors must be pinned on the Southern wall. It’s somewhat related to this belief, though personally I don’t think it makes a difference. It’s only because it’s related to Yamraj and May “symbolise” that the living person is dead (since usually you hang dead peoples photos there), it may not be mentally satisfactory or appealing

Comment: Yes my parents and elders say the same. Only deceased relatives photos to be hanged on the southern wall